# why the session on codeigniter doesnt work always redirect to login if its logged?

Tags: session, codeigniter-3

I want to the user write  http://localhost/store_websocket/ redirect me to home if it's logged or there is a session , but if not then login.i also use a custom controller called MY_Controller there's a little validation if not loggen then redirecto login, but it doesnt work , how can I fix ?

controller

```
public function getAccess(){
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('home','refresh');
        }else{
            $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
            $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
            $array = $this->user->login($username,$password);
            if ($array[0] == 0) {
               $this->json(array('error' => 'invalid username or password'));
            }else{
                $data_session = array(
                    'id' => $array[0]['id'],
                    'name' => $array[0]['nombre'],
                    'last_name' => $array[0]['apellido'],
                    'type' => $array[0]['id_perfil'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE 
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('log',$data_session);
                $this->json($data_session);
            }
        }
    }
```

ajax

```
 BASE_URL =  "<?= base_url() ?>";
         $('#login-form').submit(function(){
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            URL_GET_ACCESS = BASE_URL+"login/getAccess";
            $.ajax({
                url: URL_GET_ACCESS,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {username: username, password: password}
            }).done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.error === 'invalid username or password') {
                    $('#error').show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                    $('#username,#password').val('');
                }else if(data === '1'){
                    window.location.href=BASE_URL+'home';
                }else{
                     window.location.href=BASE_URL+'home';
                }
            });
            return false;
         });
```

MY_Controller

```
protected function isLogged(){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('log'))
            redirect('home');
    }
```

Comment: Maybe to try with `if ($this->session->userdata('log')) {`?

Comment: i tried, but when I write my url like this  http://localhost/store_websocket/ then redirect home many times how can I fix it?

Comment: I think it's because `/home` route is extending `MY_Controller`. Routes you are supposing to have for not logged in users, shouldn't have check if they are logged in.

Comment: how can I do it wiht my code without remove the extend class?

Comment: As I said, controller that is meant to be for non-logged in users can't extend parent class that is checking if user already logged in. You have to redirect user to some other controller. Take it as this: login form page or publicly visited pages are not going to extend parent controller if parent controller is checking for loggin state.

Comment: how can I fix it if I need my_controler on login?

Comment: You need MY_Controller on POST request not on GET request. Showing the form for login doesn't require MY_Controller, route that is in form action does. Have you fixed this one already?